# Image Loading takes too long using https or encoding/decoding db blobs

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried loading images from my database(encoding decoding medium blobs) and I've also tried storing the images on my server but it takes way too much time to load when I'm searching for 10+ users and attaching images to the cell.  The search works extremely fast without images...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
let cell = self.myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    if (self.countrySearchController.active)
    {
        cell!.textLabel?.text! = self.searchArray[indexPath.row]
        if (cell!.textLabel!.text! != "")
        {
            let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://www.mywebsite.com/profileimages/\(cell!.textLabel!.text!).jpg")!)
            if imageData != nil
            {
             let d  = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell!.imageView?.image = d
            }
        }

        return cell!
    }

    else
    {
        cell!.textLabel!.text! = MyVariables.users[indexPath.row] as! String
        return cell!
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Using `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` is a synchronous operation, and that's why it "seems" slow. All your network requests should be asynchronous. Also, in case of images, you should introduce some caching. You can achieve this through ios networking classes (i.e `NSURLSession`, `NSURLRequest`) or with help of libraries (such as https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: Why you don't load those images asynchronously? I suggest you to use something like [KFSwiftImageLoader](https://github.com/kiavashfaisali/KFSwiftImageLoader) to load images async and having them cached automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are downloading image synchronously, thats why its taking long to perform, i have added Async `GCD` block to download image and set. Replace your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method with following code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    if (self.countrySearchController.active)
    {
        cell!.textLabel?.text! = self.searchArray[indexPath.row]
        if (cell!.textLabel!.text! != "")
        {
            // *** GCD queue to perform Asynchronous Task ***
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                // Perform Image Downloading Task here
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://www.mywebsite.com/profileimages/\(cell!.textLabel!.text!).jpg")!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // update your Imageview with Downloaded Image
                    if imageData != nil
                    {
                        let d  = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        cell!.imageView?.image = d
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        return cell!
    }
    else
    {
        cell!.textLabel!.text! = MyVariables.users[indexPath.row] as! String
        return cell!
    }
}
```

> Even to enhance performance you can save downloaded image into your app's Documents directory and load image from it next onwards. 
>   In your case you can save Images into `NSCache` and display images from it once its downloaded.

Comment: works fast! but the problem is only some of the images load initially and then the others load later.  I know its using separate threads to pull these images which is best practice.  However, I'm only pulling 10 images which is why i'm concerned why it takes so long to get all 10 images without caching

Comment: when i store the images I compress them using  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgUI,0.0)!  Therefore, they are only 200-300kb each

Comment: @DevTonio don't store images in your database, it takes time to load from database, instead store images into Documents directory and use them. Yes, its downloading using multiple threads so each thread is independent, you can't download all together.

Comment: @DevTonio its the advantage of Asynchronous process, it doesn't hold up your UI and performs heavy operations. Once you store them in Documents directory next time load image from there it will work like charm, another option is to use `NSCache` which is also helpful in your case.

Comment: Yeah I initially had them stored in the DB.  I then modified the app to upload and download the images from my server and removed them from the db which i though would improve performance but it looks like it stayed the same

Comment: I'll look into NSCache thanks for all the help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You should load your images using multitasking. Easiest way to do this is using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) framework. It's also allows caching and setting placeholders. All what you need with this framework is something like this:

```
cell.photoView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: friend.imageUrl), placeholderImage: placeHolderImage)
```